# On the AB5 condition

Tags: abelian-categories

I'm wondering on the present issue since few days: I'd like to understand why the so-called AB5 condition fails in general for a cocomplete (i.e. AB3) abelian category, more precisely I'd like you to highline the error I'm doing in the forthcoming  thoughts.

Let $\cal A$ be a cocomplete abelian category, let $(u_i\colon A_i\hookrightarrow A)_{i\in I}$ be a direct family of subobjects of a fixed object $A\in{\cal A}$. Let $(\varinjlim A_i,(\mu_i)_{i\in I})$ be the direct limit of the family. Then *we would have*:
$$
   \varinjlim_{i\in I}A_i=\sum_{i\in I}\mathop{\rm Im}\mu_i \qquad(1)
$$
and
$$
   \alpha\circ\mu_i=u_i\quad\forall i\in I\qquad(2)
$$
where $\alpha\colon\varinjlim A_i\to A$ is the canonical morphisms.

Concerning (1), I took the canonical epimorphism $\pi\colon\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i\to\varinjlim A_i$ defining the direct limit as a cokernel, then applied the right exact functor $\bigoplus$ on the family of the factorisations $A_i\to\mathop{\rm Im}\mu_i\to \varinjlim A_i$ of the $\mu_i$'s, to find
$$
   \mathop{\rm Im}\pi=\varinjlim_{i\in I}A_i=\sum_{i\in I}\mathop{\rm Im}\mu_i
$$
as claimed. But (2) then tells me that each $\mu_i$ is a mono since $u_i$ is, whence $\mathop{\rm Im}\mu_i\cong A_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Now, I'm quite sure that I've already made a mistake so far, but in any case I'm asking you whether AB5 condition requires for the direct limit of a family of subobjects to be actually a subobject of $A$, not only an object isomorphic to a subobject of $A$. For, in the above confusing idea I should have proved that AB5 holds true in any cocomplete abelian category, which is not true in general.

Thank you!

Comment: Symbols used are taken from Popescu's book "Abelian categories and applications to rings and modules", so that $\sum$ is what e.g. Mitchell calls union in his book "Theory of categories"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you wrote is fine - but the point is that in a general Abelian category, you cannot conclude from what you wrote, i.e. $A$ restricted to directed pieces being embedded, that the whole thing is embedded.

In other words: You just passed from the direct system $(A_i)_i$ to the isomorphic direct system $(\mathrm{Im}\mu_i)_i.$ Each of them comes with a system of monomorphisms to $A$, and the task/goal is to conclude that the induced map on colimit is a monomorphism.

But the task did not really get any easier by changing the situation up to isomorphism. The thing that creates an illusion that it does is that we tend to think of images as sub*sets* of the target *set*, and so it seems that after taking union of these *sets*, one gets still a sub*set*. This works well for module categories (where Ab5 holds) but fails in general abelian categories.

Comment: Thank you @Pavel Čoupek, I though the issue was related to the fact you mentioned. Furthermore, is it the same to say that such unions are isomorphic but do not fulfil the relevant universal properties, namely those of the image?